# OpenSSL - Sign the certificate with own CA

Tags: java, applet, openssl, ca, jar-signing

I hope you can help me. I'm about to sign jar-files with a self created certificate using OpenSSL.
The jar-File contains an old Java-Applet which Java is blocking (as long as it is not signed) in the browser since version 7.51. Once it is signed, I just have to install the certificate (in the system / browser / JRE).

Right now I have a problem signing the certification request (see below "Step 7"): "unable to load certificate". What do I have to change to pass this step? In addition I am not sure about the further steps (which I also added below). Could you pls also tell me if these are right?

Thank you in advance for any help.

1.) Create folder structure

```
cd test
mkdir private certs newcerts conf export csr
echo '01' > serial
touch index.txt
export OPENSSL_CONF=/home/joerg/cacerts/myca/openssl.cnf
```

2.) Create the Certificate Authority

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -keyform PEM -outform PEM -keyout test/private/cakey.pem -out test/cacert.pem
```

3.) Copy the CA into a format which can be managed by the Java-keystore:

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in test/cacert.pem -out test/cacert.crt
```

4.) Generate Keystore

```
keytool -genkey -keystore javakeystore.jks -alias test
```

5.) Check Keystore

```
keytool -list -keystore javakeystore.jks -storepass "whatever"

Keystore-Typ: JKS
Keystore-Provider: SUN

Keystore enthält 1 Eintrag

test, 13.11.2014, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Zertifikat-Fingerprint (SHA1): 38:D0:44:2A:35:C8:60:F1:CD:7F:0E:41:6D:E6:DC:23:7C:49:96:23
```

6.) Create certification request

```
keytool -certreq -v -file test/certs/caRequest.csr -alias "test" -keystore javakeystore.jks -storepass "whatever"
```

7.) Sign the certificate with the CA

```
openssl ca -days 365 -in test/certs/caRequest.csr -out test/newcerts/caRequest.pem -policy policy_anything
Using configuration from /home/joerg/cacerts/myca/openssl.cnf
Enter pass phrase for /home/joerg/cacerts/myca/test/private/cakey.pem:
unable to load certificate
140116933408416:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
~/cacerts/myca$
```

My plan is to continue like this:

8.)

```
openssl x509 -in test/newcerts/caRequest.pem -out test/newcerts/caRequest.pem -outform PEM
```

9.)

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in test/newcerts/caRequest.pem -out test/newcerts/caRequest.crt
```

10.) Concatenate the certificate chain

```
cat test/newcerts/caRequest.pem test/cacert.pem > test/newcerts/caRequest.chain
```

11.) Indicate that I trust this CA

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -file test/cacert.pem -alias test -keystore javakeystore.jks -storepass "whatever"
```

12.) Import it into your keystore

```
keytool -import -file test\newcerts\caRequest.chain -alias test1 -keystore javakeystore.jks -storepass "whatever"
```

13.) Sign jar file

```
jarsigner -keystore javakeystore.jks TestApplet.jar test
```

Comment: You need to use the same alias when importing the signed certificate that you used when creating the keypair and CSR.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You probably mean in "Step 11". Yes, I will change that. But, right now I don't even get that far.

Comment: Oh, and in "Step 12".

Comment: No. Step 12 is the only step that imports the signed certificate. You haven't stated *why* you don't even get that far. As a matter of fact you haven't asked a question at all, only posted a list of steps for comment. So I commented.

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed it again, added the questions I have and highlighted the main part/question.